# C# Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C#, While i was following an Youtube tutorial,  i have followed everything as it is in the tutorial but receiving error "Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" while compiling. Following is the code. pl help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you build a new Solution using the Provided templates? The standard WinForms templates add a `Program` class which contains the usual entry point ,`static void Main() { ... }`, where also the starting Form is initialized and the application is run -- If you're not using Visual Studio, add the file containing the entry point yourself

Comment: Yes.. I have created new empty project and added just new Winform and compiled on visual studio..

Comment: Had you done that, ie create a new *Windows Forms project*, there wouldn't be such an error. Instead of following YouTube videos, check the [documentation tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/get-started/create-app-visual-studio?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Tried the following solution from stackOverflow but in vain.                                                                                                         "Maybe the "Output type" in properties->Application of the project must be a "Class Library" instead of console or windows application."

Comment: As others have pointed out you probably picked the wrong project type. Are you using VS or VS code?